# when does executing() return false in sqlite for flex?

Tags: apache-flex, sqlite, air

i've read the flex language reference:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#executing

> This property is true if execute() has been called and not all of the results have been returned from the database.

however, i'm having trouble understanding what that means exactly. I keep receiving an error:

> Error #3106: Property cannot be changed while SQLStatement.executing is true.

i've tried creating an event handler for SQLEvent.RESULT, my thinking was that's how the results would get returned from the database and therefore executing() would return false - didn't work.

does this mean i'm trying to change my SQLStatement variable too quickly? how long does the execute() function take?

the code in question:

```
private function fileProgress(p_evt:ProgressEvent):void {
            var char:String;
            var line:String = "";
            var counter:int = 1;

            sqlStatement = new SQLStatement();
            sqlStatement.sqlConnection = dbConn;
            while(stream.position < stream.bytesAvailable) 
            {
                char = stream.readMultiByte(1, File.systemCharset);
                if(char == "\n")
                {
                    sqlStatement.text = "INSERT INTO stats VALUES ('" + counter + "','" + line + "');";
                    sqlStatement.execute();
                    counter++;
                    line = "";
                }
                else
                {
                    line += char;
                }
                readProgress.text = ((p_evt.bytesLoaded/1048576).toFixed(2)) + "MB out of " + ((p_evt.bytesTotal/1048576).toFixed(2)) + "MB read";
            }

            if(line != "")
            {
                sqlStatement.text = "INSERT INTO stats VALUES ('" + line + "');";
                sqlStatement.execute();
            }

        }
```

stream is a filestream 
i'm trying to read a textfile and put every line into a new sqlite table row. 
i've also tried using sqlStatement.parameters as an alternative way to do my insert queries, but to no luck. that throws a different error:

> Error #3110: Operation cannot be performed while SQLStatement.executing is true.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to create a new SQLStatment for each query instead of reusing the SqlStatement.
It should work in OpenAsyn mode too.

```
var statement:SQLStatement; 
for(..) //LOOP
{
            statement =new SQLStatement();
            statement.sqlConnection = dbConn;
            statement.text="QUERY HERE";
            statement.execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [cancel()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/data/SQLStatement.html#cancel()).

Comment: just gave it a try, did not work. but i'm glad, because i dont want to cancel the sqlstatement.execute(). i want it to complete each time before being fired again

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone comes looking here, i thought i'd post my solution to this.

simply change the SQL Connection from connection.openAsync() to connection.open()

this got rid of errors for me

Comment: What you did is changing from Async mode to non asynchronous mode. While this is Ok for small apps you'd want to stay asynchronous on when using larger databases.

Answer (score 0):

When calling execute() or execute(-1) --> executing() returns false immediately (if in synchronous mode) or after the SQLResult event fires (if in asynchronous mode.)

When calling execute() with a prefetch > 0 executing() returns false only when the entire result set has been returned. For example execute(10) will return up to 10 rows.  If executing() is true that means there is more data and you will need to call next() to get the next 10 rows.  Keep calling Next() until executing() is false.  You may call cancel() anytime to quit early (like if you only wanted the first 10 rows.)